# How to use Django form fields multiple times in a GET or POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Here is what I have, a simple Django form

```
class survey (forms.Form):
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(
                                 widget = RadioSelect(),
                                 choices = answers_select
                                )
```

Now, on my HTML page, I got not just one question but many! Is it possible to use the above `answer` field for all the questions? For all the questions, its just the same choices I have to show!

Say I have 3 questions:

1. How is my restaurant
2. How is the food
3. How is the service

choices for the above `answer` field are `1. good, 2. bad 3. worst`
So, I don't want to create 3 form fields for the 3 questions as its redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step back and think it clearly through--you'll need 3 `ChoiceField` to track the answer for 3 separate questions and there's no way around it.

What would be redundant is to actually repeat the form field construction call, especially if you were dealing with, say, 20 questions. In this case, rather than statically constructing those fields, you can store the list of questions as a class invariant and create the form fields dynamically during the forms construction.

Here's something to give you a starting idea on how you might go about doing it:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    questions = _create_questions('How is my restaurant?',
                                  'How is the Food?',
                                  'How is the service?')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create the form as usual
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add custom form fields dynamically
        for question in questions:
             self.fields[question[0]] = forms.ChoiceField(label=question[1],
                                                          widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                                                          choices=answers_select)
    @classmethod
    def _create_questions(cls, *questions):
        return [(str(index), question) for index, question in enumerate(questions)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). You could do something like this:

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
SurveyFormSet = formset_factory(survey, extra=3, max_num=3)
```

Add it to your context:

```
def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(request, *args, **kwargs)
    data['formset'] = SurveyFormSet()
    return data
```

Then use it in the template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

During a post, you'll want to pass request.POST and request.FILES into the formset constructor:

```
formset = SurveyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

It's all described pretty thoroughly in that linked documentation.